# GCP: AutoML Image Classification model Deployment stuck

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deployment

We have trained and deployed an image classification model many times and are experienced users.

We have issued a deploy command to one of our models today and rather than taking the usual time to deploy (around 30-40 minutes), it is stuck in a deploying state for over three hours.

On the console, the model is showing as deploying. We were issued a long running action ID and checking this shows the action is still running.

Running an undeploy command fails as the model is not deployed. Running a deploy command fails as the model has another deployment running.

What is the timeout for this? We need to deploy and undeploy our model daily to operate important business processes.

Comment: I think I answered my own question, it threw an error after four hours. I'll post again if it gets stuck again and I can work out what to do next. Hopefully this is some kind of one-off transient deployment issue.

Comment: So this times out after about 4 hours and then we could redeploy, but yet again the deployment is just hanging. how do we get this to work? How do we even get support for this?

Comment: Can you share the relevant parts of your source code? Or even better: share a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. It's difficult, answering to a problem that diffuse ("it's not working for some reason").